# Running into "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'num1') (14)"

Tags: react-native, typeerror

I can't tell what's wrong with my code, but I'm running into this TypeError.
Here's my code; I'm trying to create a simple calculator with buttons and the code is unfinished.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableHighlight, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

let deviceHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
let deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

export default class App extends Component {
    
    state = {
        num1: 0,
        num2: 0,
        operation: '+',
        answer: Number(this.state.num1) + Number(this.state.num2)
    };
```

The error occurs on line 14: `answer: Number(this.state.num1) + Number(this.state.num2)`

```
    plus = () => {
        this.setState({
            operation: '+'
        }),
        this.setState({
            answer: Number(this.state.num1) + Number(this.state.num2)
        })
    };
    
    minus = () => {
        this.setState({
            operation: '-'
        }),
        this.setState({
            answer: Number(this.state.num1) - Number(this.state.num2)
        })
    };
    
    multiply = () => {
        this.setState({
            operation: 'x'
        }),
        this.setState({
            answer: Number(this.state.num1) * Number(this.state.num2)
        })
    };
    
    divide = () => {
        this.setState({
            operation: '/'
        }),
        this.setState({
            answer: Number(this.state.num1) / Number(this.state.num2)
        })
    };
    
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>
                    Calculator
                </Text>
                <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
                    <TextInput style={styles.textInput}
                        keyboardType = 'numeric'
                        onChangeText={(num1) => this.setState({num1})}
                        value={this.state.num1}
                    />
                    
                    <Text style={styles.textInput}>
                        {this.state.operation}
                    </Text>
                    
                    <TextInput style={styles.textInput}
                        keyboardType = 'numeric'
                        onChangeText={(num2) => this.setState({num2})}
                        value={this.state.num2}
                    />
                </View>
                
                <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
                    
                    <TouchableHighlight
                        style={styles.button}
                        onPress={this.plus}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.title}>
                            +
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far, as well as a stylesheet. If there's any other errors you can spot, I'd appreciate all the help I can get. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the state on initial setup. This is not possible.

Hence,

```js
state = {
        num1: 0,
        num2: 0,
        operation: '+',
        answer: Number(this.state.num1) + Number(this.state.num2)
    };
```

does not work. Since this is the initial state, you can just set `answer` to zero.

```js
state = {
        num1: 0,
        num2: 0,
        operation: '+',
        answer: 0
    };
```

Changing `answer` afterwards is then possible.

There is another possible issue in your code. You set the state to a new object which does not contain the attributes of the object's definition. Furthermore, you set the state twice for setting `answer` and `operation`. This will trigger two rerenders, which is unnecessary. You can set everything at once as follows using the `spread-syntax` and override the values of the state that you want to override.

```js
multiply = () => {
        this.setState(previousState => ({
            ...previousState,
            operation: 'x',
            answer: previousState.num1 * previousState.num2
        })),
    };
```